# Change background filling on c3 donut chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I've a problem with c3 library. Indeed, I have to generate many donut charts in table cells.
Charts has well generated but the background is not filled, only the first chart has the good background filling...

Here my generating code :

```
var chartTitle1dy = 0;
  var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: "#" + prefix + "_chart_" + scopeId + "_" + chartSiteId,
    size: {
      height: 75
    },
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['show', value],
        ['dontshow', dontShow]
      ],
      type: 'donut',
      order: null
    },
    color: {
      pattern: ['green', 'white']
    },
    legend: {
      show: false
    },
    donut: {
      label: {
        show: false
      },
      width: 5,
      expand: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      show: true,
      contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
        var $$ = this, config = $$.config,
          titleFormat = config.tooltip_format_title || defaultTitleFormat,
          nameFormat = config.tooltip_format_name || function (name) { return name; },
          valueFormat = config.tooltip_format_value || defaultValueFormat,
          text, i, title, value, name, bgcolor;
        for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
          if (! (d[i] && (d[i].value || d[i].value === 0))) { continue; }

          if (! text) {
            title = titleFormat ? titleFormat(d[i].x) : d[i].x;
            text = "<table class='"
              + $$.CLASS.tooltip + "'>"
              + (title || title === 0 ? "<tr><th colspan='2' style='text-align: center;'>"
              + title
              + "</th></tr>" : "");
          }

          name = nameFormat(d[i].name);
          value = valueFormat(d[i].value, d[i].ratio, d[i].id, d[i].index);
          bgcolor = $$.levelColor ? $$.levelColor(d[i].value) : color(d[i].id);

          text += "<tr class='" + $$.CLASS.tooltipName + "-" + d[i].id + "'>";
          text += "<td class='value' colspan='2' style='text-align: center;'>" + value + "</td>";
          text += "</tr>";
        }
        return text + "</table>";
      },
      format: {
        title: function() {return 'Details'},
        value: function() {
          return numerator + ' / ' + denominator;
        }
      }
    }
  });
// overide the chart title
  var label = d3.select('#myDifferentIdForEachChart text.c3-chart-arcs-title');
  label.html(''); // remove existant text
  label.insert('tspan')
    .text(Number(value) + "%")
    .attr('fill', '#000')
    .attr('dy', chartTitle1dy)
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr("style", "font-size: 0.7em");

  // grey background to fill center of donut
    d3.select("td .c3 .c3-chart")
      .insert("circle", ":first-child")
      .attr("cx", chart.internal.width / 2)
      .attr("cy", chart.internal.height / 2 - chart.internal.margin.top)
      .attr("r", chart.internal.innerRadius)
      .attr("fill", "#d3d3d3")
    ;
```

[image: Glitch screenshot]

And there the result with my glitch, every value with "%" are charts, but filled with white color instead of lightgray.

Could you help me to fix it please ?

Thanks by advance,

Comment: Not sure, but could it be that the filling is only applied to the first child, because of `.insert("circle", ":first-child")` ?

Comment: No, each code pasted in my question is for one chart and each chart is composed with several "circle" marks, so this code is selecting the first one for filling it

However you put finger on something ! The selector was wrong, I have to select with #myId .c3-chart and cot only .c3 .c3-chart which select only first one.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution lies in changing this:

```
d3.select("td .c3 .c3-chart")
```

d3.select only selects the *first* element that matches (from https://github.com/d3/d3-selection):

> [d3.select] Selects the first element that matches the specified selector string. If no elements match the selector, returns an empty selection. If multiple elements match the selector, only the first matching element (in document order) will be selected.

if you use

```
d3.selectAll("td .c3 .c3-chart").attr("fill", "#d3d3d3")...
```

you should be able to set the background color of all your charts at once.